# Working batch for loop does not work in different computer

Tags: loops, for-loop, batch-file, windows-10

I have the simplest loop in a batch file to count the number of files in a path. It works and I have been using it for a while now. However, I tried to run it in a different computer, and results come out empty. Code is as simple as it can get:

```
for /F %%A in ('dir ^| find "File(s)"') do set cnt=%%A
echo Number of files in path is %cnt%
```

What I get is:

> Number of files in path is =

What am I missing? It runs correctly in Win10x64b and I'm also trying to run it in Win10x64b on a different computer with no luck.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does that "different computer" happen to have a different language?

Comment: A language independent method: `for /f %%A in ('dir /b /a-d ^|find /c /v ""') do echo %%A`

Comment: That's it! As the programming noob I am, I wasn't aware that it was language sensitive. This worked like a charm! Thanks so much!

Comment: A basic FOR command would have worked as well. `FOR %%G IN (*) DO SET /A "cnt+=1"`

Comment: not only this breaks when the language changes, it'll also break when there's a file whose name containing `File(s)` [script works fine on one machine and not on others, why?](https://superuser.com/a/935280/241386)